# Use the value within a cell in a vlookup formula

Tags: excel

I would like to take the percentile of the db_main!AA:AA but without having to type it.

Basically, I want to have a cell = AA and then use concatenate and "something" to do my percentile. Can anyone explain how to do this. Does it involve using Indirect?

```
=PERCENTILE(db_main!AA:AA,0.25)
```

Here is what I tried so far

```
=PERCENTILE(CONCATENATE("db_main!",INDIRECT("N15",TRUE),":",INDIRECT("N15",TRUE)),0.25)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what your problem is exactly? I dont understand it.

Comment: i want to be able to reference a cell to take the percentile of a column on a different sheet without having to type the formula each time

Comment: Your question is still really unclear. You're misusing `INDIRECT`, by the way. Let's say that `N15` contains the value "AA". To reference "db_main!AA:AA" you'd need `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("db_main!",N15,":",N15),TRUE)`

Comment: To everybody else: I figured now was not the time to shorten things up to `INDIRECT("db_main!"&N15&":"&N15)`

Comment: I agree with what Dane has commented here. Dane, you should submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still unclear, but the one thing that is immediately clear is that you're misusing `INDIRECT`.

Let's say that `N15` contains the value "AA". To reference "db_main!AA:AA" you can use `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("db_main!",N15,":",N15),TRUE)` as your array reference.

You can shorten that to `INDIRECT("db_main!"&N15&":"&N15)`, since `&` works for concatenating and `INDIRECT` defaults to the "A1" style.